# Are tissue culture questions in the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Tissue culture is:

> the growth in an artificial medium of cells derived from living tissue.

My question is whether or not tissue culture questions are appropriate for this site. One might argue that it would be more appropriate in Biology.SE. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked questions on tissue culture on Biology, but I think it could possibly be on topic here if the question is more about transitioning to normal gardening, or maintaining a rare potato cultivar, or something, rather than details on how the cells divide, why certain nutrients should be left out, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's more a topic for [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

There's a line in our FAQ section [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> - plant biology, beyond what is generally gardening knowledge (try Biology),

while the [Biology FAQ](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a line item:

> - questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

The term "tissue culture" brings to mind images of microscopes and Petri dishes and cells growing in an agar jelly medium, none of which are typical gardening equipment. The purpose of tissue culture is generally to study how plants grow at a cellular level, again not a typical gardening concern (though I've seen a documentary where plants are cloned by culturing individual cells in a lab, a gardener typically clones plants using a pruner and maybe some hormone rooting powder).

Answer (score 1):

I think the topic is out of scope for here. None of the gardening courses or books I have ever taken or read refer to tissue culture.  It is used but on a commercial basis.